# A good UI widget to select multiple ranges?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a suitable jquery-ui widget or a bootstrap widget for selecting multiple ranges out of a dataset that don't overlap each other and are configurable?

For example, I have a dataset ranging between 0-10M units.

I need to be able to select exclusive ranges like < 10K, 10K-30K, 30K-200K, 200K-800K etc...

and assign something to each range.

Is there a idiomatic widget that already does major chunk of the requirement ?

Answer (score -1):

**UI multi select plugin**

Why dont you try 
[**this**](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/) jquery plugin . works well and good ui as well .

Comment: I want to be able to chnage range values.
for eg : 0-10 10-20 20-40 40-60 60-100

Then if I decided to make it to 0-30 30-100.
I should be able to do taht easily!